# How to add only Owners of Office group to SharePoint group?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

Recently I've been tinkering with a lot of the things on SharePoint Online because my company (I'm an Intern doing research) wants to move from On-premise to SharePoint Online. I've noticed that you can add/reference other Office365 groups when attempting to add Users to a SharePoint group, However, I'm only able to add Office365 group members whereas I might want to add only the Owners of an Office365 group.

For example, lets say I have an Office365 group called 'IT Dept' with 2 owners and 2 members. Lets say I have an 'Accounting' Team site with the standard 3 SharePoint Groups ('Accounting Members', 'Accounting Owners', 'Accounting Visitors') and I want to add only the Owners of the O365 group 'IT Dept' to the 'Accounting Owners' SharePoint group. It appears that I can add/reference the O365 group 'IT Dept' as 'IT Dept Members' but I don't see an option for 'IT Dept Owners' .

Is this not a feature or am I just not seeing the reference because of security reasons? If this works for others, please let me know! Let's assume I'm the Owner of both the O365 groups and the Team Site (If that matters).

Thanks in advance,

Tyler T

Answer (score 0):

There is no separate group that is created by default that can be used for only applying permissions to the owners of the group. A group for the "members" is created which include all of the members and owners of the O365 group.

So there is nothing that your missing, it's the actual default behavior.

You could get around this by creating a separate security group in the admin center, then, add that security group to the O365 group owners. The same security group can then be used to give permissions on other SharePoint sites.

Comment: You can't add/reference security groups in Office groups. You can do it another security group but not in an Office group.